# Qlik Sense API: Viewing data from a .qvf file in my Angular application

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

Alright, I'm new to working with the Qlik API and wanted to know if you can help me extract the data from a table from a .qvf file and filter it as if I were launching SQL queries or something similar.

For now I show the data that a table contains using this structure:

```
    {
          "handle": 1,
          "method": "GetTableData",
          "params": {
            "qOffset": 0,
            "qRows": 1500,
            "qSyntheticMode": true,
            "qTableName": "Hoja1$"
          },
          "outKey": -1,
        }
    
      }
```

How can I filter the data I retrieve?

It is that I want to show the data in some KPIs developed in a FronEnd in angular.

Thank you very much greetings!